# Result of promise in node.js is not getting passed through to HTML correctly?

Tags: html, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have the following function which takes the promise object from an async function and then attempts to set a text element in the html file to the result value as such:

```
function test(){
runSample().then(function(result){

  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "lol";
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = result;
});
}
```

I call this function in my html document before the end of the body section after I've declared the p1 + p2 elements as such:

```
        <script>
test();
        </script>
```

What am I missing, why is the result not getting passed through correctly?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of your async function.

Comment: Looks good, except for the missing error handling. What exactly do you mean by "*result not getting passed through correctly?*"

Comment: @bergi well when I open my index.html file the p1 and p2 elements are not getting updated to "lol" and the result value.

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari it's just an implementation of the dialogflow node js as seen here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow

Comment: @stevenpatrick9 So yeah, then the promise returned by `runSample` is getting rejected, or never fulfills. Please post the full code. I assume you're not getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: `runSample()`, as given in [the reference](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) doesn't return its `result`.